# Can we check whether property is readonly in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I tried to use getOwnPropertyDescriptor method but either normal property or readonly property is always writable in return?
Do you know any way to check it?

```js
class MyClass {
  public readonly id : number = 0
}

const instance = new MyClass()

var itsReadonly = isItReadOnly(instance.id)
```

Comment: Please add you code. We can barely help without.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two kinds of `readonly`-ness when it comes to TypeScript: compile time `readonly`-ness and runtime `readonly`-ness.

Since there is no code presented in OP, I guess, according to the question, the code is like:

```js
class Foo {
    readonly a = 1
    b = 2
}
```

We can define a helper function to check the `readonly`-ness of a property of a given object

```js
function isWritable<T extends Object>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) || {}
    return Boolean(desc.writable)
}
```

Then we can check the `readonly`-ness:

```js
const foo = new Foo
console.log(isWritable(foo, 'a'), isWritable(foo, 'b'))
// true true
```

It is printing `true true` because `foo.a` and `foo.b` are both writable **at runtime** since `readonly` keyword in TypeScript does nothing to the emitted JavaScript code.

If we inspect the emitted code of `Foo` (targeting ES6):

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.a = 1;
        this.b = 2;
    }
}
```

There is no difference between `a` and `b` at all.

However, if you assign a new value to `foo.a` in TypeScript, the type system would complain that `a` is a readonly property. This is exactly what the `readonly` keyword does: **it only provides a compile time constraint but could never affect the runtime behavior**.

```js
foo.a = 1 // Cannot assign to 'a' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
foo.b = 3 // correct
```

If a runtime readonly property is wanted, then the `get` syntax could be used.

```js
class Zoo {
    get a () { return 1 }
    b = 2
}
```

And emitted code would be:

```js
class Zoo {
    constructor() {
        this.b = 2;
    }
    get a() { return 1; }
}
```

Since the getter exists on the prototype rather than the instance, we need to modify `isWritable` function a little bit to cover the `getter`.

```
function isWritable<T extends Object>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
    const desc = 
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) 
        || Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), key)
        || {}
    return Boolean(desc.writable)
}
```

Then we check the `readonly`-ness again:

```js
const zoo = new Zoo

console.log(isWritable(zoo, 'a'), isWritable(zoo, 'b'))
// false true
```

Now `zoo.a` is readonly both in compile time and run time.

```js
zoo.a = 1
// Type check fails (compile time): Cannot assign to 'a' because it is a constant or a read-only property.
// Throws an error (run time): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property a of #<Zoo> which has only a getter
zoo.b = 3 //correct
```

[Try online](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%20a%20%3D%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20isWritable%3CT%20extends%20Object%3E(obj%3A%20T%2C%20key%3A%20keyof%20T)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20desc%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj%2C%20key)%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%7C%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)%2C%20key)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Boolean(desc.writable)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(isWritable(foo%2C%20%27a%27)%2C%20isWritable(foo%2C%20%27b%27))%0D%0A%2F%2F%20true%20true%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo.a%20%3D%201%20%2F%2F%20Cannot%20assign%20to%20%27a%27%20because%20it%20is%20a%20constant%20or%20a%20read-only%20property.%0D%0Afoo.b%20%3D%203%20%2F%2F%20correct%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Zoo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20a%20()%20%7B%20return%201%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20zoo%20%3D%20new%20Zoo%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(isWritable(zoo%2C%20%27a%27)%2C%20isWritable(zoo%2C%20%27b%27))%0D%0A%2F%2F%20false%20true%0D%0A%0D%0Azoo.a%20%3D%201%20%2F%2F%20Cannot%20assign%20to%20%27a%27%20because%20it%20is%20a%20read-only%20property.%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Note%20the%20runtime%20error%20in%20the%20console%20after%20runing%20the%20emitted%20code.%0D%0Azoo.b%20%3D%203%0D%0A%0D%0A)

**CAVEAT**

The modified `isWritable` is still inperfect as it only checks one level upwards along the prototype chain. A complete solution should climb the prototype chain until find a descriptor or reach the end.